# Knockout binding using jquery templates using facebook response data

Tags: jquery, facebook, knockout.js

Using Knockout 2.3.0 with the jQuery Templates Plugin 1.0.0pre when access Facebook Albums and Photos,

Using a dependentObservable with a call to an authenticated Facebook user's account for any photos within a known album id

```
     ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            var id = 'me';

            if (viewModel.currentAlbum()) {
                id = viewModel.currentAlbum().id;
            }

            viewModel.loadingPhotos(true);
            FB.api(id + '/photos', { limit: 11, offset: viewModel.currentPage() * 10 }, function (response) {
                var truncatedResponse = response.data;

                if (truncatedResponse.length > 10) {
                    truncatedResponse.pop(); //remove the excess item
                    viewModel.nextPage(true);
                } else {
                    viewModel.nextPage(false);
                }


                viewModel.photoItems(ko.utils.arrayMap(response.data, function (s) {
                    return s;
                }, viewModel)),
                viewModel.loadingPhotos(false);
            });

        }, viewModel);
```

With a ViewModel

```
        var viewModel = {
            userId: user.id,
            userName: user.name,
            loadingPhotos: ko.observable(true),
            albums: ko.observableArray([]),
            photos: ko.observableArray([]),
            photoItems: ko.observableArray([]),
            currentPage: ko.observable(0),
            nextPage: ko.observable(false),
            currentPhoto: ko.observable(undefined),
            currentAlbum: ko.observable(undefined),

            selectPhoto: function (photo) {
                viewModel.currentPhoto(photo);
            },

            submitImage: function () {
                if (viewModel.currentPhoto()) {
                    $('#resultPane').show();
                    $('#resultImage').attr('src', viewModel.currentPhoto().source);
                    $('#container').hide();
                }
            },
        };
```

and some markup

```
    <div id="body">
        <div data-bind="visible: photoItems().length === 0">There are no photos in this album</div>
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'photosTemplate', foreach: photoItems, as: 'photo' } ">         
        </ul>
        <div data-bind="visible: loadingPhotos">Loading...</div>
        <button data-bind="click: function () { currentPage(currentPage() - 1); }, enable: currentPage() > 0">&lt;</button>
        <button data-bind="click: function () { currentPage(currentPage() + 1); }, enable: nextPage">&gt;</button>
    </div>
```

And a template markup as such;

```
<script type="text/html" id="photosTemplate">
    <li data-bind="click: function () { viewModel._self.selectPhoto($data); }"><img data-bind="    css: { selected: viewModel._self.currentPhoto === $data }" src="photo.picture}"/></li>
</script>
```

example of the response.data

{

```
"id": "10151241718347535",
"from": { "name": "Foo Foo MyAlbums", "id": "631022535" },

"picture": "https:\/\/fbcdn-photos-b-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-frc3\/417631_10151241718347504_140582535_s.jpg",

"source": "https:\/\/fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-frc3\/s720x720\/417631_10151241718347504_140582535_n.jpg",
"height": 540,
"width": 720,
"images": [{ "height": 1536, "width": 2048, "source": "https:\/\/fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-frc1\/858093_10151241718347504_140582535_o.jpg" }, { "height": 960, "width": 1280, "source": "https:\/\/fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-frc1\/p960x960\/858093_10151241718347504_140582131_o.jpg" }, { "height": 720, "width": 960, "source": "https:\/\/fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-frc3\/417631_10151241718347504_140582535_n.jpg" },
        { "height": 600, "width": 800, "source": "https:\/\/fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-frc1\/p600x600\/858093_10151241718347504_140582535_o.jpg" },
        { "height": 480, "width": 640, "source": "https:\/\/fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-frc3\/p480x480\/417631_10151241718347504_140582535_n.jpg" },
        { "height": 320, "width": 426, "source": "https:\/\/fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-frc3\/p320x320\/417631_10151241718347504_140582535_n.jpg" },
        { "height": 540, "width": 720, "source": "https:\/\/fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-frc1\/p180x540\/858093_10151241718347504_140582535_o.jpg" },
        { "height": 130, "width": 173, "source": "https:\/\/fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-frc3\/p130x130\/417631_10151241718347504_140582535_n.jpg" },
        { "height": 225, "width": 300, "source": "https:\/\/fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net\/hphotos-ak-frc3\/p75x225\/417631_10151241718347504_140582535_n.jpg" }
],


"link": "https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/photo.php?fbid=101512417183475354&set=a.10151241718337504.1073741825.631022505&type=1",
"icon": "https:\/\/fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yz\/r\/StEh3RhPvjk.gif",
"created_time": "2013-03-01T04:17:31+0000",
"updated_time": "2013-03-01T04:17:31+0000"
```

}

What seems to happen with the 'viewModel.photoItems' is that the observableArray contains a single entry(when the know results are greater than 1) and we're unable to access the property value of the foreach item(s) inside the template  ie: 'photo.picture'   As an alternate, I have tried using viewModel.photos(response.data) without success. 
Any suggestions are appreciated.

***Updated:***

The 'viewModel.photoItems' did have each item.  The UI was breaking because of a condition within the template;

Changed the template to:

```
  <script type="text/html" id="photosTemplate">
     <li data-bind="click: function () { $parent.selectPhoto($data); }" ><img data-bind="    attr: { src: photo.picture }" /></li>
</script>
```

All seem well.